# Error due to rvalue to lvalue conversion and not using forward

Tags: c++, c++11, perfect-forwarding

The following code shows a segmentation fault both in windows & Linux machines. The `Parent` class stores a pointer, but due to rvalue to lvalue conversion, the `Parent` ends up storing a reference to a pointer.
(This is as per my understanding, please correct it otherwise)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Root {
public:
    virtual void Print() = 0;
};

template<typename PointerType>
class Parent : public Root {
public:
    Parent(PointerType&& p): ptr(p) {}

    void Print() override {
        std::cout <<"About to deref ptr" << std::endl;
        std::cout << *ptr << std::endl;
    }

    PointerType ptr;
};

class Child {
public:
    Root * root;
    template<typename PointerType>
    Child(PointerType&& p) {
        root = new Parent<PointerType>(std::forward<PointerType>(p));
    }
};



std::vector<Child> v;

template<typename PointerType>
void MyFunction(PointerType&& ptr) {  

    Child ch(ptr); /// ptr is lvalue here

    /// FIX : Child ch(std::forward<PointerType>(ptr));

    v.push_back(std::move(ch));
}

int* getInt() {
    return new int(10);
}

int main() {
    MyFunction(getInt()); /// pass any rvalue pointer /// it could be "this" pointer also
    v[0].root->Print();
}
```

I convinced myself that, I **always** need to use `std::forward` as in when `universal references` are used (Inside the function `MyFunction`).

I am finding it difficult to understand the following

Why does reference to `ptr` becomes invalid inside the `parent` class? Is it because `ptr` becomes a local variable once it is used inside `MyFunction` and `Child` constructor gets a reference to this local only?

Thanks!

Comment: Quick note: By declaring a constructor for `Child` you are in fact blocking implicit creation of move constructor and thus `std::move(ch)` is useless , consider switching to `v.emplace_back(std::forward<PointerType>(ptr));` or forcefully generate move constructor ( `Child(Child&&) noexcept = default` )

Comment: @fvalasiad oh..that I missed, thanks for letting me know. But that is not related to the main problem, right? just asking for clarification.

Comment: Your code compiles and runs just fine to me so i don't understand what your problem is , perhaps show us what you expect and what results you get instead

Comment: @fvalasiad : The code has a dangling reference, and crashes when actually _run_. I found the question sufficiently clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, here's what's happening, keeping in mind that `getInt` returns an rvalue: when you *don't* forward `ptr`, you end up invoking (post-reference collapsing)

- `MyFunction<int*>(int*&&)`
- which invokes `Child::Child<int*&>(int*&)`
- which constructs and stores a `Parent<int*&>`.

When you *do* forward `ptr`, you end up invoking

- `MyFunction<int*>(int*&&)`
- which invokes `Child::Child<int*>(int*&&)`
- which constructs and stores a `Parent<int*>`.

So the manifestation of the problem is a common dangling reference: `Parent<int*&>::ptr` is necessarily an `int*&`, which happens to be bound to the temporary returned by `getInt`. However, the solution is a little more complicated than just dogmatically applying `std::forward`..:

It so happens that forwarding `ptr` fixes the problem here, because you are passing an rvalue into `MyFunction` in your example; but you should certainly be able to call `MyFunction` with an lvalue and have it work properly, and `forward` alone doesn't solve that. The *actual* problem is instantiating `Parent` with a reference type to begin with; in C++11 this is generally avoided via application of [`std::decay`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/decay).

Once this is fixed, a second problem will become apparent (masked by luck in your current code due to reference collapsing rules): the `PointerType&&` in parent's constructor is not a forwarding reference, because `PointerType` is a parameter of the type, not the constructor. As a result, when an lvalue is passed in, the constructor invoked will end up being `Parent<int*>::Parent(int*&&)`, which in turn will not compile. Unfortunately the 'proper' solution to *this* is complicated in C++11... The short summary is that if you want perfect-forwarding to apply to `Parent`'s constructor, that constructor needs to become a template; but implementing this *correctly* is complicated and verbose in older standards, so I'll leave researching that as an exercise for the reader and choose the easy solution here: accept by value and move.

With both of these fixed the result looks like:

```
template<typename PointerType>
class Parent : public Root {
public:
    Parent(PointerType p): ptr(std::move(p)) {}

    void Print() override {
        std::cout << "About to deref ptr\n" << *ptr << '\n';
    }

    PointerType ptr;
};

class Child {
public:
    Root* root;

    template<typename PointerType>
    Child(PointerType&& p):
        root(new Parent<typename std::decay<PointerType>::type>(
            std::forward<PointerType>(p)
        ))
    {}
};
```

<kbd>**[Online Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c7a6449d94af7d05)**</kbd>

(But then one has to wonder, do 'pointer types' really warrant perfect-forwarding in the first place?)

Comment: Thanks for mentioning the `std::decay`.